# Change text color/background in PDF on click using embedded JavaScript

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf-generation

I had in mind idea of generating pdf documents, that can switch between light and dark theme (i.e. black text on white background and vice versa) when user clicks a lint/text/button in PDF itself.

I know you can embed JavaScript in PDF, I checked [Acrobat specification](https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/acrobatsdk/pdfs/acrobatsdk_jsapiref.pdf) but found no mention of changing text color/background or any concept like layouts.

Is it something that can be done using embedded JavaScript? And ideally, would it work in embedded Chrome pdf viewer? I know it has very limited subset of functions (more details [here](https://github.com/osnr/horrifying-pdf-experiments))

Comment: I believe it can be done if you place the dark and light variants of your design on separate layers (in Adobe InDesign). https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-discussions/interactive-pdf-with-buttons-the-show-layers-independently-from-each-other-but-at-the-same-time/m-p/10445259